# Animating Crossfading between two images - Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, splash-screen, graphical-logo

I am creating a splash screen for my app using multiple images.  I have one main image that will be displayed as a Logo; behind the logo I intend to have two images - a green cloud, and a blue cloud, fading in and out a few times so it will create a kind of pulsing glow effect behind the logo.  What is the best way to implement this type of effect?  Basically the main image will stay static while the other two images switch back and forth from one to the other until the end of the splash intro.  Thanks in advance for the help! BTW I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have two images stacked - one way is in ht linear layout keep blue cloud as background and in the frame layout keep an `ImageView`. In the ImageView hold the green cloud. Now make the transparency of the image in the frame layout ("green cloud") fade in  and fade out with its transparency. Call `setAlpha` in a loop -cycle the the argument to set Alpha - 0 is fully transparent wherein "blue cloud" is visible and 255 is fully opaque - "green cloud" is visible.